# If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, is $\Gamma$ always finite in Classical and Intuitionistic Logic?

Tags: logic

I've been studying the Compactness Theorem in van Dalen's *Logic and Structure*. In the book, its proof seems to assume that every derivation has a finite number of premises. But this is not explicitly said in the text, as far as I know.

Here is van Dalen's proof (p.111):

> $⇒$: Suppose $Γ$ has no model, then by the Model Existence Lemma $Γ$ is inconsistent, i.e. $Γ \vdash ⊥$. **Therefore there are $σ_1,...,σ_n ∈ Γ$ such that $σ_1,...,σ_n \vdash ⊥$**. This shows that $∆ = {σ_1,...,σ_n}$ has no model.

My problem is how to justify the bold passage.

Is it true then that if $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, $\Gamma$ is always finite in Classical (and Intuitionistic Logic)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully not, otherwise set theory would be no fun at all!  When we prove a theorem $\phi$ of ordinary mathematics, we end up showing that $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \phi$, and the axioms $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are most definitely an infinite set of sentences.

Writing $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ means that there is a proof of $\phi$, in which we are allowed to use as premises any of the sentences from the set $\Gamma$, as well as any axioms of logic.  Nobody says we have to use *all* the sentences from $\Gamma$.  Indeed, if $\Gamma$ is infinite, we *can't*: our proof can only have finitely many lines, so we can't even mention all the sentences from $\Gamma$, much less use them in an essential way.  So in fact, if we get a proof of $\phi$, we can look back and see which sentences from $\Gamma$ we used.  We can only have used finitely many, and all the others were not actually needed.  With enough foresight, we could have started with a smaller set $\Gamma_0$ that only contained the finitely many sentences we were actually going to use.

And that is essentially the proof of the compactness theorem: if $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, there is a finite $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \vdash \phi$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

No, we are often interested in infinite $\Gamma$. But because a proof is a finite sequence of sentences, it can only invoke finitely many axioms; so if $\Gamma\vdash \varphi$ then some finite subset of $\Gamma$ suffices to prove $\varphi$. Van Dalen is taking this for granted (it's a straightforward exercise) in the bolded sentence.

This is true of classical and intuitionistic logic, and in general of any logic where a proof is a finite object.